# "differently" vs. "different" in a certain sentence

Tags: grammar

I found the following text in an article at http://www.thedailystar.net/frontpage/few-hours-left-nomination-74341 :

> In Chittagong, the AL and the BNP were not worried as only one person from each party has collected nomination papers.
>
> **It's a differently story** in the councillors' race. More than 560 individuals, most of them of AL and BNP, have collected nomination papers.

Is the use of "differently" correct here?  I expected it to be "different".

Answer (score 2):

***Different***, which is an **adjective**. An adjective is "a word...serving as a modifier of a noun"[1]. *Story* is a noun and, thus, ***different* is the correct form**.

***Differently***, on the other hand, is an **adverb**. An adverb is "a word that describes a verb, an adjective, or another adverb"[2]. Since *story* is a noun (and not a verb, adjective, or adverb), *differently* would not be the correct form.

[1] http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjective

[2] http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adverb

Answer (score 0):

You need an **adjective**, "different," to qualify the noun "story," not the adverb "differently," which is used to qualify /verbs/actions/.